# Looping grease pencil animation error

Tags: modifiers, add-on, grease-pencil, 2d

I tried to apply the Time Offset modifier to a grease pencil animation with Storyboard add-on, but it does not create looping animation. What could be possible reasons for that/how to fix it?

I am animating a scene in Storyboard add-on, could that be the reason for modifiers not working? I tried to make a loop in a different file, without storyboard add-on and it worked. Furthermore, i tried adding noise modifier as well, and similar to time offset, it didn’t work.

I would be very grateful for any advice/recommendations.